# Oracle. Missing keyword when using case statement. Error 00905

Tags: sql, oracle

I keep getting an error 'ORA-00905: missing keyword' with the following statement, ever since I introduced the CASE statement, but I can't figure out what is missing.

```
SELECT
    CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.STARTTIME,
    CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME
FROM
  CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN
WHERE
  (
   CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME  > 
    (SELECT SYSDATE,
        CASE SYSDATE
            WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH') < 6 THEN CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
            ELSE CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
        END AS SYSDATE
    FROM DUAL
    )
   AND
   CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME  <= SYSDATE
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damien_The_Unbeliever is right about mixing case styles, but you also don't need the subquery at all, and the one you have is getting two columns back - which you can't compare with a single value. You can just do this:

```
WHERE
   CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME > CASE
        WHEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24')) < 6
          THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '6' HOUR
        ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '6' HOUR END
   AND CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME  <= SYSDATE
```

This leaves the comparison as between two dates, rather than relying on implcit conversions. I've also used `HH24`; using `HH` would treat times between midday and 6pm the same as those between midnight and 6am, which I'm prety sure you didn't intend.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot Alex!!

It made me realise the THEN and ELSE statements needed to be switched

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing up the two forms of `CASE` expressions. There's a simple expression (when you're just wanting to compare expressions for equality):

```
CASE Expr1
    WHEN Expr2 THEN ...
    WHEN Expr3 THEN ...
    ELSE ...
END
```

And there's a searched `CASE` expression, where you want to evaluate separate predicates:

```
CASE
    WHEN Predicate1 THEN ...
    WHEN Predicate2 THEN ...
    ELSE ...
END
```

For a searched `CASE`, you don't specify an expression between `CASE` and the first `WHEN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT
    CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.STARTTIME,
    CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME
FROM
  CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN
WHERE
  (
   CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME  > 
    (SELECT SYSDATE,
        CASE 
            WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH') < 6 THEN CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
            ELSE CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
        END AS "MY_SYSDATE"
    FROM DUAL
    )
   AND
   CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME  <= SYSDATE
  )
```

There two possible mistakes, one is it is expecting as `CASE WHEN` not as `CASE sysdate WHEN` and second one is `sysdate` as alias which is not possible to use as alias name.

Comment: This gives a "Too many values" error...would that be because that returns SYSDATE and MY_SYSDATE and so it can't evaluate CYCLE_S_FACT_MAIN.ENDTIME > (SYSDATE, MY_SYSDATE)?
How could we fix that?

Comment: @RichardMaguire - why do you want it to be greater than both? The next clause says it has to be `<= sysdate`, so it can't be `> sysdate` at the same time. You might need to step back and clarify what logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: Ok, needs to return just one value, either yesterdays date at 06:00:00 if the current hour of the day < 6 else todays date at 06:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH'),
     CASE
          WHEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH') < 6
          THEN CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
          ELSE CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
     END "sysdate" ,
     TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH'),
     CONCAT(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), ' 06:00:00')
FROM dual;
```

---

```
12  24-07-2013 06:00:00 12  25-07-2013 06:00:00
```

Comment: Too many values being returned by that CASE statement, needs to return just one value, either yesterdays date at 06:00:00 if the current hour of the day <6 else todays date at 06:00:00

Comment: I given the valid query, not the value to display