# Missing Keyword when using CASE in UPDATE in ORACLE query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

MY_TABLE has following columns
ELEMENT_ID     NUMBER(9)
SEQ_NAME       VARCHAR2(30)

I want to update the ELEMENT_ID column's value for all the rows in the table according to below logic for which I have written a 'case' statement in UPDATE query. But when I am running this query I am getting error

**ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement**

Cursor goes to '2' in the first THEN.

**Can someone help in finding what is the problem ?**

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
    SET MY_TABLE.ELEMENT_ID = (
        CASE MY_TABLE.SEQ_NAME 
            WHEN  'APD' 
                THEN ((APD_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2)

             WHEN 'BC'
                THEN (BC_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'CEB'             
                THEN (CEB_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'DDT'             
                THEN (DDT_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'ETA'             
                THEN (ETA_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'EMD'             
                THEN (EMD_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'HH'             
                THEN (HH_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'OR'
                THEN (OR_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'RT'
                THEN (RT_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'UM'
                THEN (UM_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2

             WHEN 'VT'
                THEN (VT_SQ.NEXTVAL * 10) + 2
        END
     )
   ;
```

---

I had checked this, but this does not help me

[Oracle. Missing keyword when using case statement. Error 00905](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17851139/oracle-missing-keyword-when-using-case-statement-error-00905)

Comment: The "answer" I posted below might be seen purely as a question, but your query will not work while it references tables/aliases that the query is not accessing. Have you supplied the complete query?

Comment: Are you getting ORA-00900: missing keyword, or ORA-00900: invalid statement? What you've shown looks fine; unless your client doesn't like the blank lines in the middle of the statement, which could cause either error depending on which part(s) it tries to run. Might be helpful to say which client and version you're running, or just try it without the blank lines.